# Why the image disappear whenever I enter a name and click on?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is the code I have for the "State Name Game", everything seems work well, but when I enter a name of a state, the image disappears and the name of that state name is written on the screen but without the image. So, basically I wanna the name stay after I enter the name of a state.Thank you very much.

```
import pandas
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()

# add image onto the screen
screen.title("U.S. States Game")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)

# create state name list
data = pandas.read_csv("50_states.csv")
all_names = data.state.to_list()
name_list = []

# write the name of the State onto the screen
while len(name_list) < 50:
    guess_name = screen.textinput(title=f"{len(name_list)}/50 States Correct",
                                  prompt="Input the name of a state ").title()
    if guess_name == "Exit":
        missing_states = []
        for state in all_names:
            if state not in name_list:
                missing_states.append(state)
        df = pandas.DataFrame(missing_states)
        df.to_csv("missing_states.csv")
        break

    if guess_name in all_names:
        name_list.append(guess_name)
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.penup()
        row_data = data[data.state == guess_name]
        turtle.goto(int(row_data.x), int(row_data.y))
        turtle.write(guess_name)
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Can you [edit] to copy-paste the text in? If I want to run this screenshot, I have to retype the whole thing by hand or use OCR to get the text out. Please also share any relevant assets (images, CSVs) to make the example a fully runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are ultimately two problems with your implementation.

1. The image is vanishing after the user enters a state name because you call `turtle.hideturtle()`, which hides the map, and never follow it with `turtle.showturtle()`
2. However, even if you did call `turtle.showTurtle`, you'll see the map moving around within the window as you are also calling `turtle.goto()` to move the pen to write the state name in.

The solution is to use two Turtle objects - one for the map image, and a second to fill in the state name.  In this example, I've named them `map` and `labels` respectively

```
import pandas
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

map = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
# create second Turtle to handle writing the labels - hidden by default
labels = Turtle(visible=False)
labels.penup()


# add image onto the screen
screen.title("U.S. States Game")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)
map.shape(image)

# create state name list
data = pandas.read_csv("50_states.csv")
all_names = data.state.to_list()
name_list = []

# write the name of the State onto the screen
while len(name_list) < 50:
    guess_name = screen.textinput(title=f"{len(name_list)}/50 States Correct",
                                  prompt="Input the name of a state ").title()
    if guess_name == "Exit":
        missing_states = []
        for state in all_names:
            if state not in name_list:
                missing_states.append(state)
        df = pandas.DataFrame(missing_states)
        df.to_csv("missing_states.csv")
        break

    if guess_name in all_names:
        name_list.append(guess_name)
        row_data = data[data.state == guess_name]
        labels.goto(int(row_data.x), int(row_data.y))
        labels.write(guess_name)
```